# Meaning of ‘I suspected her motives in offering to help.’

Tags: meaning

> I suspected her motives in offering to help.

What does it mean? As I Know here 'I' subject 'suspected' verb 'her motives' complement 'in offering to help' is modifier. But the comprehension is not clear to me.

Comment: In this sentence you could replace "suspected" with "doubted" or "did not trust".  Does that make it clear?

Comment: And who offers to help whom? Does it mean that she offered me for helping her and I've doubt in her motives (like if there other purposes on her mind)  .

Comment: She offers to help the speaker.  The speaker is suspicious of her motives in making this offer.